# custom adapter to has this error RecyclerView No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want show a data in mi app, but a cannot display for this error:

RecyclerView No adapter attached; skipping layout

this is my MainActivity, where i dislay my information, i think is a problem with my custom Adapter "CurpAdapter" and for this reason, the app dont show nothing of my info, the information is saved in firebase project and i cant display in console.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference database;
private List<Curp> curps;
private RecyclerView reciclador;
RecyclerView.Adapter adap;
private CurpAdapter cupadapter;
List<Curp> lista=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    reciclador=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.reciclador);
    LinearLayoutManager lim=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    lim.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    reciclador.setLayoutManager(lim);

    database.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Curp value=new Curp();
            value=(Curp) dataSnapshot.getValue(Curp.class);

            lista.add(value);
            cupadapter=new CurpAdapter(lista);
            adap = new CurpAdapter(lista);
            reciclador.setAdapter(adap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });

}
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    DatabaseReference conditionRef= database.child("root");
}

public void lanzar(View view){
    Intent generar = new Intent(this, Generar.class);
    startActivity(generar);
}
```

}

and this si my Custom adapater CurpAdapter class

```
public class CurpAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CurpAdapter.curpHolder> {

private List<Curp> curps;

public CurpAdapter(List<Curp> curps) {
    this.curps = curps;
}

@Override
public curpHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);
    return new curpHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(curpHolder holder, int position) {
    Curp curpc=curps.get(position);
    holder.curpCpompleto.setText(curpc.curpGen);
    holder.iniciales.setText(curpc.curpGen.substring(0,3));
    holder.imagen.setImageLevel(0);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

public class curpHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView imagen;
    TextView iniciales, curpCpompleto;

    public curpHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        iniciales=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.iniciales);
        curpCpompleto=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.curpCompleta);
        imagen=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to create adapter before `database.addChildEventListener`. It means these two line below should be moved from `addChildEventListener` and called before it:

```
adap = new CurpAdapter(lista);
reciclador.setAdapter(adap);
```

This will create adapter containing empty list of data at the beginning of `onCreate` method.

Next you have to add method setData in your CurpAdapter. It will look like this:

```
public void setData(List<Curp> curps){
    this.curps = curps.
}
```

Now in `onChildAdded` after `lista.add(value);` you have to call

```
adap.setData(list);
adap.notifyDataSetChange()
```